# Django Q objects and m2m queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-q

I'm totally flummoxed by this behavior.  I clearly don't understand Q objects like I thought I did or I'm doing something massively stupid and obvious.  Here's what I'm running into.  accepted_attendee_* are all m2m relationships to OfficialProfile.  In the django shell, for ease of demonstration.

```
>>> profile = OfficialProfile.objects.get(user__username='testofficial3')
>>> r = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(accepted_attendee_referee=profile)
>>> l = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(accepted_attendee_linesman=profile)
>>> o = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(accepted_attendee_official=profile)
>>> r
[<SchedulerEvent: andrew>]
>>> l
[]
>>> o
[]
```

This is all as expected.  Now tho, if I combine together with a Q object, things get weird.

```
>>> qevents = SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(Q(accepted_attendee_referee=profile)|Q(accepted_attendee_official=profile)|Q(accepted_attendee_linesman=profile))
>>> qevents
[<SchedulerEvent: andrew>, <SchedulerEvent: andrew>]
```

Two objects are returned, both with the same PK - two duplicate objects.  Should be only one, based on the individual queries.  But once again, when I do this:

```
>>> r|l|o
[<SchedulerEvent: andrew>, <SchedulerEvent: andrew>]
```

What is it about this OR query that returns two objects when there should, I believe quite clearly, be only one?

**EDIT**

So I looked at the query that was produced and it seems like the "answer" has nothing to do with Q objects or the OR'ing at all; rather, it's the way the ORM joins the table.  Here's the SQL and the results it generates, absent the OR:

```
mysql> SELECT `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`user_id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`title`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`description`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`start`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`end`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`location_id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`age_level_id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`skill_level_id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`officiating_system_id`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`auto_schedule`, `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`is_scheduled` 
FROM `scheduler_schedulerevent` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_referee` 
ON ( `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`id` = `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_referee`.`schedulerevent_id` ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_linesman` 
ON ( `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`id` = `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_linesman`.`schedulerevent_id` ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_official` 
ON ( `scheduler_schedulerevent`.`id` = `scheduler_schedulerevent_accepted_attendee_official`.`schedulerevent_id` );

+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------+
| id | user_id | title         | description | start               | end                 | location_id | age_level_id | skill_level_id | officiating_system_id | auto_schedule | is_scheduled |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 | Test Event    |             | 2015-04-09 02:00:00 | 2015-04-09 02:30:00 |         161 |            1 |              1 |                     3 |             0 |            0 |
|  2 |       1 | Test          |             | 2015-04-07 20:00:00 | 2015-04-07 21:00:00 |         161 |            1 |              1 |                     3 |             1 |            0 |
|  3 |       1 | Test Auto     |             | 2015-04-07 20:00:00 | 2015-04-07 20:30:00 |         161 |            1 |              1 |                     2 |             0 |            0 |
|  4 |       1 | Test Official |             | 2015-04-16 19:00:00 | 2015-04-16 20:30:00 |         161 |            1 |              1 |                     3 |             0 |            1 |
|  4 |       1 | Test Official |             | 2015-04-16 19:00:00 | 2015-04-16 20:30:00 |         161 |            1 |              1 |                     3 |             0 |            1 |
+----+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

and then clearly, when you add an OR, it satisfies two query conditions based on the results of the join.  So while adding distinct to the query *seems* unnecessary, it is quite necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting two objects and it is the same, is because that object satisfies at least two queryset.

In other words, `<SchedulerEvent: andrew>` satisfy with at least two queryset `r l o`

If you don't want duplicate objects, use `.distinct()` function.

```
SchedulerEvent.objects.filter(Q(accepted_attendee_referee=profile)|Q(accepted_attendee_official=profile)
|Q(accepted_attendee_linesman=profile)).distinct()
```

Comment: I realize I can use distinct, but that doesn't answer the question about how and why the object satisfies two quesysets.  It's basically the same query, combined with or clause.  if >>> r.count()+l.count()+o.count() equals 1 how the heck can >>> qevents.count() equal 2?  Seriously, am I being thick?

Answer (score 1):

No you aren't being thick , but just accept that the underlying system (django's ORM) and Q objects will match 2 elements which are the same and therefore only one is actually matched. Q objects are very powerful when used correctly such as searching a query in a database. In this example you do not need Q objects but a simple filter would work fine.

Have you tried how a simple `.filter(...)` behaves in your case?

In the end you are not trying to understand why it is so that Q objects will return that queryset; you are trying to get a certain result, and `distinct()` works fine :)